# How do I Cluster Hibernate ORM Identifiers when using GenerationType.Table

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, orm, replication

I'm using the Hibernate ORM with MySQL on the Amazon Cloud using a load balancer.

I'm now switching to GenerationType.Table and I'm wondering how you go about clustering hibernate so that I don't run into an issue where IDs are in conflict between multiple machines?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can cluster your middleware without having to cluster your database. This will imply using a caching solution to accommodate more traffic.

When the time comes for clustering your DB, the easiest set-up is a master-slave replication, where writes go to the master mode only. This way, you don't have to worry about PK conflicts.

For multi-master replication, MySQL offers [support for clustering the `AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://scale-out-blog.blogspot.ro/2012/04/if-you-must-deploy-multi-master.html) PRIMARY KEY, but for the [`TABLE` generator](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-identity-sequence-and-table-sequence-generator/), you might get conflicts. More, the [`TABLE` generator scales poorly compared to `IDENTITY`](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-never-use-the-table-identifier-generator-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

For the multi-master replication, I think you're better off using [UUID Primary Keys](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-and-uuid-identifiers/), to avoid conflicts between master inserting data concurrently. However, [UUIDs don't mix well with the InnoDB clustered index approach](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/100468/mysql-innodb-clustering-index-with-uuid).